# Migrate from mythbuntu 18.04 to xubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, lts, mythbuntu

I've been running a mythbuntu machine for the best part of 10 years now. I don't use the MythTV stuff any more but it runs as bit of a quasi home server. Over the years I've set up and configured a LOT of stuff, a lot of it I probably don't even remember. I'd like to keep this machine reasonably up to date but really don't want to do a fresh install and reconfigure everything. Is there a way to migrate the system to something light like say xubuntu and upgrade it to 20.04 without a new install?

At the moment I can't update to 20.04:

```
phil@htpcserver:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is your home in a separate partition or is it in the same partition as root?

Comment: Home folder is in the same partition

Comment: I would recommend baking up your data and do a fresh install, but if yo really want to avoid that, create a separate home partition https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/, then do a fresh install of Xubuntu, choose the Something else option and make sure you set the new home partition as your new home.

Answer (score 0):

Mythbuntu is discontinued since 4 years. You can't upgrade to any flavor of 20.04. You have to do a fresh install.

Comment: Yeah was hoping to avoid that. Funny though that I was able to upgrade to 18.04 without issue a couple of years ago

Comment: You can still try with: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && update-manager -cd`

Comment: Thanks. Well that does give me the option to upgrade to 20.04 (not quite ready to pull the trigger yet). However it's saying that it's a development release. I thought it was a full release by now? I guess this is the reason its not presented as an option  with "sudo do-release-upgrade" yet? I'm thinking if I can update to 20.04 at some point I can then install xfce and remove mythbuntu desktop. Is that a reasonable course of action?

Comment: Don't worry, it's a LTS release, not a Dev release.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 20 is possible. I went from mythbuntu on Ubuntu 16 -> Ubuntu 18 LTS with no problems. I then upgraded to Ubuntu 20 LTS, and again it went mostly OK.

The one gotcha is that mythfilldatabase takes a very long time (~45 minutes) since moving to 20 and mysql 8.x. Not sure why.

The mythtv project had [a page on MySQL tuning,](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Tune_MySQL) but it's really about MySQL 5.x and several lines of the suggested config file need to be commented out for MySQL 8 to start. And...even with that config, mythfilldatabase still runs slowly.

Comment: Thanks. Mythfilldatabase is not an issue for me as I no longer use mythtv

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, I did manage to get this done some time ago. From memory I ran the command recommended by NicholasSmith above to update to 20.04. I then installed Xubuntu desktop and uninstalled all the mythbuntu stuff. Went surprisingly smoothly as I recall. Still running well.